# use of dot notation and bracket to display properties inside for...in loop

Tags: javascript

I have seen some previously asked questions.But it is still not quite clear to me when i can use dot/bracket notation to display object's properties ,that's why i am here to ask this question.Here i have two examples .In my first example console.log shows object properties with dot notation ,but shows undefined with brackets

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var obj={
   name:'lol',
   age:10
}
console.log(obj[name]);
console.log(obj.name);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in my second example i used a for...in method to iterate over the object properties.In this case dot notation didn't work but bracket notation does.But if console.log() key it shows the property name.If so,then why it is having problem showing the property values??**I mean if key===name which is a property ,then obj.key should be equivalent to obj.name** which should not have any problem to show its value in my opinion.
here is the second one:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
   var obj={
      name:'lol',
      age:10
      }
for(key in obj){
   console.log(key);
   console.log(obj.key);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `obj[name]` => `obj["name"]` name here is a string not an object or variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use square bracket notation when:

- The property name is stored in a variable *or*
- The property name contains characters that are not allowed in an identifier

It is generally considered to be good style to use dot notation when you aren't required to use square bracket notation by the above rules.

---

```
var name = "foo";
obj.foo === obj["foo"] === obj[name]; // All equivalent (but the middle one is generally considered to be poor style)

var other = "one-two";
obj[other] === obj["one-two"]; // Equivalent


// obj.one-two; would be "Subtract two from obj.one".
var obj = { one: 1 };
var two = 2;
(obj.one-two) === (obj.one - two) === -1;
```

Comment: nice explanation....:) .. i didn't get the second example though.can you explain it a little??

Comment: Define "second example". What don't you understand about it?

Comment: "obj.one-two; would be "Subtract two from obj.one"... do you mean it is equivalent ot obj.one-obj.two??

Comment: No, `two` is the variable `two`.